# Setting a default value in my Enum Function

Tags: c++

My question is this: how do I set the default value in my function of type Enum, to be one of the values in the Enum. This is my first experience with Enumerations and enumerated functions. I know a decent amount about Intro/Beginner C++.

Example.. Setting the Default value to return HANDHELD ?

Also any advice on making better/clearer questions would be appreciated.

```
ComputerType SellerList::ReadAndReturnComputerType() const
{
      char type[MAX_NAME_LEN];
      cin >> type;

      if(strcmp(type, "desktop") == 0)
         return DESKTOP;
      else if (strcmp(type, "laptop") == 0)
         return LAPTOP;
      else if(strcmp(type, "tablet") == 0)
         return TABLET;
      else if(strcmp(type, "handheld") == 0)
         return HANDHELD;

 }
```

Comment: `else return HANDHELD;` ?

Comment: That was one of my ideas. I had heard that there was a way you could do it before even beginning the if statement. If this would be the simplest way, then thank you!

Comment: Also, all if cases here end in a return, no reason to use "else". And just append a "return HANDHELD;" in the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want set the default value before if statement

```
ComputerType SellerList::ReadAndReturnComputerType() const
{
      ComputerType defType = HANDHELD;
      char type[MAX_NAME_LEN];
      cin >> type;

      if(strcmp(type, "desktop") == 0)
         type = DESKTOP;
      else if (strcmp(type, "laptop") == 0)
         type = LAPTOP;
      else if(strcmp(type, "tablet") == 0)
         type = TABLET;
      else if(strcmp(type, "handheld") == 0)
         type = HANDHELD;
      return defType;
 }
```

Comment: I appreciate it. This is exactly what I was looking for. I'll be sure to accept the answer in a few minutes. Thank you Bryan.

Comment: obviously the "type = " assignments should say "defType = " such that they actually have an effect. I would recommend to rename "type" -> "typeString" and "defType" -> "result".

Answer (score 1):

Please don't do that kindda of stuff with `strcmp` and `else if` all over the place... You're doing c++ !

**At least** do something like the following piece of code. It's a lot more maintenable and with a bit of improvement you can handle the conversion enum/string and string/enum with the same map (you can even use [bimap](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/bimap/doc/html/boost_bimap/one_minute_tutorial.html) for this !).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>   

enum ComputerType
{
    DESKTOP,
    LAPTOP,
    TABLET,
    HANDHELD
};

ComputerType ReadAndReturnComputerType()
{
    // I assume this is not multithread othewise there wouldn't be any cin
    static std::map<std::string, ComputerType> type { 
        { "desktop", DESKTOP },
        { "laptop", LAPTOP },
        { "tablet", TABLET },
        { "handheld", HANDHELD } };

    std::string input;
    std::cin >> input;

    auto it = type.find(input);

    // Don't forget to clean the input here !
    // something like:
    //
    // boost::trim(input);
    // boost::to_lower(input);

    if (type.end() == it)
    {
        return HANDHELD;
    }
    return it->second;
}
```

Comment: I don't agree. Why make things slower and more complicated using complex containers when all you want to do is a simple mapping?

Comment: @TilmanVogel Slower ? When you're talking about `std::cin` and `std::map` access, this is not a consideration :). But if it's the case (and I do think map can be faster than a bunch of strcmp comparison but we have to test), `unordered_map` will certainly be better. More complicated ? mmmh matter of point of view. I find it a lot more readable and thus simpler. But I think it is a lot safer to avoid `strcmp` and `if ... else if .. else if ...` statements all over the place where you can easily miss a thing.

Comment: I agree that using a proper string class is much better, but I don't see an advantage in using a map instead of some simple if's. The story is different if you had a larger mapping where map or unordered_map could start shining but for such a small set of cases, the binary search in map or the extra hash calculation for unordered_map will just cause worse performance because the exact key comparison still needs to be done in both cases after finding a comparison candidate (by either binary search or hash lookup).

Comment: Ok for the perf, you're right the example is small. ;) The "objective" advantages I see for the map are: the easier extensibility (one line in the initializer) and the ease of the inversion of the conversion (yeah ok, easier with `bimap` but you could also do it with the `map`). What I fear most from such a code is from the `char[]` part that will one day come from outside the function without the `\0`. So yeah `std::string` definitely. `std::map` is bonus for me. :)

Comment: This was part of a 2 man project I was working on. We ran into the issue of 1 of 2 options to use and just wanted to get help with respect to the fact that I have no knowledge of Mapping or anything beyond my 5 months in the course. Thank you though, I'll have to do more research on how to use mapping and more advanced material.